# How to get code cover for Enum class in APEX

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I have a Enum class as:

```
global class Util {
global enum Session {
    Winter,
    Summer,
    Rain
}
```

}

and a test class as :

```
public static testmethod void callTestData(){
    test.starttest();
        Util.Session se = Util.Session.Winter;
    test.stoptest();
}
```

But still my code coverage is 0%?? Why.

Also I tried many ways to cover it but not able to can any one help!!

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it should give you 100% coverage.

Sometimes Salesforce needs a bit of encouragement to give you the correct code coverage results.

Try:

- Clearing all previous test case results
  Setup > App Setup > Develop > Apex Text Execution > View Test History > Clear Test Results
- Running the test case from the force.com IDE
- That the class and the test method class are using the same API version in the metadata file. E.g. both 29.0.
- Running the test case from an external tool, such as [MavensMate in Sublime Text](http://mavensmate.com/) or the [FuseIT SFDC Explorer](http://www.fuseit.com/en/Solutions/SFDC-Explorer.aspx) that has both synchronous and asynchronous testing options.